# Way to send multiple values for column to MySQL?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am creating a plugin that allows the user to select multiple options (as a checkbox), which sends these integer values to MySQL. The way I have this set up at the moment is by taking these values and passing them as a comma separate string. Then I take this string, remove the comma's, and pass the integer's as data. This intuitively doesn't seem like the most efficient way to accomplish what I am trying to do, so is there another method that can work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by using the array format. First you have to take all the selected values to form an array , you can implement this by giving the checkbox name as an array . By doing this you will get the array of selected check boxes in the name variable. You can also encode the array using Json_encode() before sending to database.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='One'>1<br>
```

Comment: I did have the name set to checkbox[], but using json_encode() is probably a superior way of doing it than the way I mentioned. thank you.

Comment: glad to know it worked for you.. Always happy to help